# convert char array to enum array?

Tags: c#, linq

Our app uses a string to house character-values used to indicate enum values. for ex, the enum for aligning cells in a table:

```
enum CellAlignment
{
    Left = 1,
    Center = 2,
    Right = 3
}
```

and the string used to represent alignments for a table of 5 columns: `"12312"`. Is there a snappy way to use LINQ to convert this string into `CellAlignment[] cellAlignments`?

here's what I've resorted to:

```
//convert string into character array
char[] cCellAligns = "12312".ToCharArray();

int itemCount = cCellAligns.Count();

int[] iCellAlignments = new int[itemCount];

//loop thru char array to populate corresponding int array
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++)
    iCellAlignments[i] = Int32.Parse(cCellAligns[i].ToString());

//convert int array to enum array
CellAlignment[] cellAlignments = iCellAlignments.Cast<CellAlignment>().Select(foo => foo).ToArray();
```

...ive tried this but it said specified cast not valid:

```
CellAlignment[] cellAlignmentsX = cCellAligns.Cast<CellAlignment>().Select(foo => foo).ToArray();
```

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
var enumValues = text.Select(c => (CellAlignment)(c - '0'))
                     .ToArray();
```

That *assumes* all the values are valid, of course... it uses the fact that you can subtract '0' from any digit character to get the value of that digit, and that you can explicitly convert from `int` to `CellAlignment`.

Comment: thanks, this is super short. since the enum is based on ints, i believe converting explicitly is better than parsing.

Answer (score 4):

Using a Linq projection and `Enum.Parse`:

```
string input = "12312";
CellAlignment[] cellAlignments = input.Select(c => (CellAlignment)Enum.Parse(typeof(CellAlignment), c.ToString()))
                                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Array.ConvertAll function something like this:

```
CellAlignment[] alignments = Array.ConvertAll("12312", x => (CellAlignment)Int32.Parse(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var s = "12312";
s.Select(x => (CellAlignment)int.Parse(x.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop

```
List<CellAlignment> cellAlignments = new List<CellAlignment>();

foreach( int i in iCellAlignments)
{
    cellAlignments.Add((CellAlignment)Enum.Parse(typeof(CellAlignment), i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: trying to do w/ LINQ and not iterating loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to the following;

```
int[] iCellAlignments = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };
        CellAlignment[] temp = new CellAlignment[5];


        for (int i = 0; i < iCellAlignments.Length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] =(CellAlignment)iCellAlignments[i];
        }
```

Comment: trying to do w/ LINQ and not iterating loops.